# Rails3 ActionMailer deliveries in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, development-environment, actionmailer

Is it possible to send mailers in the development environment?

I've added this to my development.rb file:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :address              => "mail.email.com",
  :port                 => 25,
  :domain               => 'email.com',
  :user_name            => 'email@email.com',
  :password             => 'password',
  :authentication       => 'plain',
  :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

Then I run `UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver` in rails console which returns `#<Mail::Message:2265713480, Multipart: true, Headers: <Date: Thu...` but I never actually receive the email. Is there something else I need to configure?

Oh, and if I check `ActionMailer::Base.deliveries` it returns an empty hash `=> []`.

Comment: Try setting `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` so you can see if there is an exception.

Comment: ah yes! That did spit out an error `Net::SMTPUnknownError: * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.`. I guess my SMTP settings are wrong. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Thanks @ctcherry, I've now got this working. Just had to tweak some smtp settings, and turn off tls.

Comment: What smtp settings did you tweak?

Comment: @Cycle, just added an answer to this question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to add the following to `environments/development.rb`:

```
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
```